# Fixed/Scrolling Divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to set some section headings to remain fixed, but then scroll up with the page when the user reaches the next heading. Example: http://www.codeandtheory.com/about-us.

My markup:

```
<div class="section-title"><div class="section-bar"></div>
 <a href="#collections"><p class="section-title">Collections Management</p></a>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.section-title {
    width: 270px;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 38px;
    color: #f18a21;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
```

Test link: http://api.mtscollective.com

Can this be done in pure CSS, or is JS required?

Thanks!

Comment: @dwreck08 Ah. Can you recommend any existing solutions?

Answer (score 3):

Js is required!

try this to the same

**jQuery**

```
<script>     
$(window).scroll(function(){
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
          $('.section-title').addClass('fixed');
      } else {
          $('.section-title').removeClass('fixed');
      }
  });
</script>
```

and **CSS:**

```
.fixed {position:fixed; top:0; left:0;}
```

Comment: Thanks! Should it be `.section-title` instead of `#section-title`? I see what the script is doing, but it doesn't seem to take effect on scroll. Updated http://api.mtscollective.com

Comment: my mistake..it should be `.section-title`